# Azure function application insight configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, configuration-files, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I would like to customize the application insight configuration for an azure function by creating telemetry initializer. My current scope of work is to identify a way to correlate messages sent from an HTTP triggered azure function to another HTTP triggered azure function and for that was trying to follow the help at [dzimchuk.net](https://dzimchuk.net/event-correlation-in-application-insights/). However I do not see an ApplicationInsights.config in my azure function project. I found the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-customer-reviews) that includes an app insight configuration file, and hence not sure how that project was created. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config , we know the file is automatically added to your project when you install most versions of the SDK. But in your Github link:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-customer-reviews/blob/master/Source/ContentModeratorFunction/ContentModeratorFunction.csproj , there is no related Microsoft.ApplicationInsights packages.So it’s really strange  why there is a file. Besides, there still  are some features not  supported  about application insight in Azure function.

Comment: Yes, for normal projects the file is added when adding the nugget packages. However when adding app insight packages to function projects it is not added. I wonder from where azure functions pick up these settings or if these are at all configurable

Comment: I hope my answer would be help. It seems that the telemetry initializer  just supports in web project(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling) ,there is not related article in Azure function. There is still some features missed in Azure function( like trace dependency authomatically).You could read this article(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/05/10/application-insights-integration-with-functions-now-in-preview/).

Comment: Thanks for your continued help in this regard @JanleyZhang. I see from the link you provided that dependency support is still not there. This partly answers my question. I am still not having an answer to why the github sample project references the .config file. Perhaps there could be some bypass mechanism to extend the function? I am trying to test out that function with few changes. Hence if you don't mind I would still like to keep this thread open.

Answer (score 0):

Functions v2 has the capability to do this, but it isn't directly supported.

> **[Warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services)**
>
> Do not add AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() to the services collection as it registers services that conflict with services provided by the environment.
>
> **Do not register your own TelemetryConfiguration or TelemetryClient if you are using the built-in Application Insights functionality.**

Closest I've gotten is this [comment on a github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3741#issuecomment-541219519) which tries to preserve the existing functionality.

There are a few others I've seen around but many of them break integrations with Azure Portal such as the Quick Pulse (Live metrics feed) and performance metrics.